# Seeking Help Uploading and Processing PDF using Tesseract OCR in Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, ocr, tesseract

A link to working colab notebook would be ideal. I'm looking for a Google Colab notebook that allows for easy PDF upload and performs OCR using Tesseract. Requirements are straightforward: upload a PDF as input without a text layer, and output identical PDF with searchable text layer. Also would be awesome if it allowed me to use a pdf from google drive or dropbox as the input.

I've tried a couple from github I found via google searches, and none have worked yet. A couple I tried already:

- https://colab.research.google.com/github/suyesha07/Optical-Character-Reader/blob/main/OCR.ipynb
- https://colab.research.google.com/github/vistec-AI/colab/blob/master/easyocr.ipynb

I also tried writing my own google colab, but it fails at the "for i, page in enumerate(pages):" line.  Admittedly, I don't really know what I'm doing but tried anyway. Here's that [link to the colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1rD8EuuBo6F1Vrjjz3x2Zq19IQOnHAffC?usp=sharing).